# tkinter: strange order of operations in bound events, how to change?

Tags: tkinter, focus

This is related to [Controlling Order of Callbacks with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478105/controlling-order-of-callbacks-with-tkinter) but is not quite the same thing

I have an Entry field (tk.Entry) and a checkbox field (tk.Checkbutton). I bind to the Entry's FocusOut, and the checkbox is given a command= to run when it is checked. These both get fired, but...

In many situations, the user enters text, and, knowing I handle FocusOut as a way to commit the text change, he doesn't bother to hit Return. He just goes and clicks on the associated checkbox, secure in the knowledge that of course the text change will be committed before the checkbox changes state. And this matters; both the text change and the checkmark state get shipped off to a server as they happen, which will decide if the checkmark state is legitimate, based on the the text.

The problem is "as they happen". For whatever reason, tkinter decides to fire off the checkmark change first, and only afterwards gets around to firing the FocusOut on the text field. I'm on ubuntu, but I (and my users) are used to Windows SDK apps, where that wouldn't happen. The result is that the server sees the checkbox being set when the text is (as far as it's been told) in a bad state, error paths get taken, evil things occur, users gnash teeth, I get threatened with dentist bills, etc.

This doesn't make sense to me. The checkbox should have to receive focus in order to process the click; to get focus, the Entry widgit should have had to give it up. But tkinter clearly doesn't agree.

I tried setting focus to the checkmark in the checkmark's command handler, but it's clearly too late. tkinter's not going to stop and call FocusOut at that point. I could in theory have the checkmark command handler reach over to the textbox and send that content first, but for complex reasons the checkmark's code doesn't even know the text field exists, and changing that would be quite hard. I could presumably have the checkmark command queue an "after" operation after 50ms to send the checkmark state, but then I'm racing against users with quick fingers.

To my mind this is a tkinter bug - checkbutton receives focus when clicked, handles space as a way to toggle, it's just like anything else that can take focus. It looks to me as if tkinter is briefly asserting focus belongs to 2 widgits by reporting about it in the wrong order. But on the guess that tkinter is not going to change, and in the certain knowledge that users are not going to stop and hit Return after editing every text field, is there some clever workaround?

As requested, code. Sorry about the length but I wanted to keep all the binds in case they matter. Follow the directions displayed and the result shows up in the title bar (and stdout).

```
"""See line 130 to enable the hackAround
Python 3.6.7 linux mint
"""

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font

myFont = None
zerowidth = 10
tkinterHandle = None
firstThingsFirst = False

#infrastructure, ignore
class About:
    def __init__(self, isA, info):
        self.typeIs = isA

#infrastructure, ignore
class Cmd:
    def __init__(self, name, about, text):
        self.about = about
        self.name = name
        self.text = text

#holds a widget, base class of specific widget types
class WidgetHolder: 
    def __init__(self, name, about):
        self.widgit = None
        self.name = name
        self.about = about
        self.parentW = self.about.widgit 

    def canTakeFocus(self):
        try: #apparently not everything has a 'state'.
            if self.widgit['state'] == "disabled":
                return False
        except: #sigh
            pass
        return isinstance(self.widgit, tk.Entry) or isinstance(self.widgit, ttk.Button)\
              or isinstance(self.widgit, ttk.Combobox) or isinstance(self.widgit, tk.Checkbutton)\
              or isinstance(self.widgit, ScrolledText)

    def set(self, t):
        self.apply(t)

    def doEnable(self, b):
        pass

    def setErrorColor(self):
        pass

#Holds an Entry
class SingleLineInputOnAPage(WidgetHolder):
    def __init__(self, c):
        WidgetHolder.__init__(self, c.name, c.about)
        self.txt = tk.StringVar()
        vcmd = (self.parentW.register(self.onValidate), '%P')

        #key, not mouse or something?
        self.widgit = tk.Entry(self.parentW,   validate="key",
                          validatecommand=vcmd, textvariable=self.txt, font=myFont, width=0)
        self.savedText = c.text
        self.apply(c.text)
        self.widgit.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: self.timeToSend()))
        self.widgit.bind("<Key-ISO_Left_Tab>", (lambda event: self.doNot()))
        self.widgit.bind("<Tab>", (lambda event: self.doNot()))
        self.widgit.bind("<Button>", (lambda event: self.click(event)))
        self.widgit.bind("<FocusIn>", (lambda event: self.save()))
        self.widgit.bind("<FocusOut>", (lambda event: self.timeToSendMaybe()))
        self.widgit.bind("<Escape>", (lambda event: self.gotEsc()))
        self.widgit.bind("<Control-s>", (lambda event: self.timeToSend()))
        self.widgit.bind("<Control-a>", (lambda event: self.selectAll()))

    def gotEsc(self):
        pass
    def doNot(self):
        print("Reproduing the problem does not involve tab!")

    def save(self):
        self.savedText = self.txt.get()

    def timeToSendMaybe(self):
        self.timeToSend()

    def click(self, event):
        pass

    def setErrorColor(self):
        self.widgit.config(background="#ff5000")

    def selectAll(self):
        self.widgit.select_range(0, 'end')
        return 'break'

    def timeToSend(self):
        self.savedText = self.txt.get()
        global firstThingsFirst
        firstThingsFirst = True
        print("Ideally this happens first. Entry text would be sent now:", self.savedText)
        return 'break'

    def apply(self, t):
        self.savedText = t
        self.txt.set(t)

    def onValidate(self, P):
      return True

#Holds a checkbox
class CheckboxOnAPage(WidgetHolder):
    def __init__(self, c, cmd):
        WidgetHolder.__init__(self, c.name, c.about)
        if cmd == None:
            cmd = self.fire
        self.value = tk.IntVar()
        self.widgit = tk.Checkbutton(self.parentW, text="", variable=self.value, command=self.fire)
        self.apply(c.text)
        #self.widgit.bind("<Key-ISO_Left_Tab>", (lambda event: self.timeToSendMaybeAndPrev()))
        #self.widgit.bind("<Tab>", (lambda event: self.timeToSendMaybeAndNext()))

    def apply(self, t):
        pass

    def fire(self):
        self.widgit.focus()
        v = "X"[0:self.value.get()]

        #to get things in a better order, set to True
        if False:
          global tkinterHandle #clumsy, is there a way to get  self.widgit from the tk instance? 
          tkinterHandle.after(30, lambda sendthis=v: self.push(sendthis))
        else:
          self.push(v)

    def push(self, v):
        print("Checkmark ", v, " would be sent now. Ideally this does not happen first")
        global firstThingsFirst
        if firstThingsFirst:
          tkinterHandle.title("In order")
        else:
          tkinterHandle.title("Out of order!")


class CharSheet(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, argThing, *args, **kwargs):
        global myFont
        global zerowidth
        global tkinterHandle 

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("360x80")
        self.title("Out of order?")

        myFont = tk.font.Font(family="Courier", size=10)
        zerowidth=myFont.measure("0")
        tkinterHandle = self
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        abt2 = About("C", "")
        abt2.widgit = container
        cmd2 = Cmd("b", abt2, "give me focus; then click checkbox")
        w2 = SingleLineInputOnAPage(cmd2)
        w2.widgit.pack()

        abt = About("C", "")
        abt.widgit = container
        cmd = Cmd("a", abt, "")
        w1 = CheckboxOnAPage(cmd, None)
        w1.widgit.pack()

CharSheet(None).mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley done.

Comment: That code isn’t _minimal_. There is a lot of code that is unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: I don't plan to go through the exercise of selectively removing binds to see if some combination of them makes the problem goes away. The other "lot of code" is about 30 lines of infrastructure that I don't think poses an obstacle. Basically, I demonstrated the problem in an easy to run way, and I have my workaround,  documented in that sample, so other people won't bang their heads in this like I did. If you don't care to run it that's fine. I fully expect the response would be "huh, funny old tkinter, but that's just the way it works." By documenting the issue I've served my purpose.

Comment: _"I don't plan to go through the exercise of selectively removing binds to see if some combination of them makes the problem goes away."_  That's certainly your choice. You'll have an easier time attracting people who want to help if you make it as easy as possible to understand the code.

Comment: But having demonstrated that the events come back in an unreasonable or at least unexpected order (take my word for it if you don't want to run the code), and on the premise that the binds I am doing should not interfere with the order of things (I think a reasonable assumption), does this amount to a bug or an aspect?  I feel as if it's a bug, but I'm having trouble finding anything like comprehensive documentation on tkinter. Or where I'd submit a big report, if this is one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To my mind this is a tkinter bug - checkbutton receives focus when clicked,

No, this isn't a tkinter bug. Tkinter is performing as designed. The standard checkbutton does not receive focus when clicked. The ttk checkbutton does, however.

> It looks to me as if tkinter is briefly asserting focus belongs to 2 widgits by reporting about it in the wrong order.

That is an incorrect assessment. It is impossible for focus to be on more than one widget at a time.

The problem is that you are explicitly setting the focus to the checkbutton, but you are not giving the tkinter event loop a chance to process the `<FocusOut>` event before continuing. Therefore, even though you think the focus is on the checkbutton, it is not. The focus can't change until tkinter has a chance to process the request for the focus to change.

A quick, hacky solution is to call `update` after changing the focus, which gives tkinter a chance to process all pending events. However, calling `update` can be tricky if there are pending events that may cause the handler to be called again. My personal rule of thumb is to never call `update` unless strictly necessary.

If your main goal is to have the focus change to the checkbutton (and thus force the entry widget `<FocusOut>` binding to be processed before the checkbutton click), you can create a binding on the widget class (`Checkbutton`), which is processed before the button handler. That, or use a ttk checkbutton which changes the focus automatically.

### A proper minimal reproducible example

I'm not going to show you how to change your code because it's far too complex to serve as a good minimal example. Instead, here is a program that illustrates the problem.

Start with this base code, which serves as a minimal reproducible example for the problem you observe. Notice that when you click on the entry and then click on the checkbutton, the order that is displayed in the text widget is first the checkbutton click and then the focus change.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.cb = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, command=self.handle_checkbutton, text="Click me")
        self.text = tk.Text(self.root, height=8, width=80, background="bisque")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.root, command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.cb.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.entry.insert(0, "click here, then click on the checkbutton")

        self.entry.bind("<FocusOut>", self.handle_focus_out)
        self.entry.focus_set()

    def handle_focus_out(self, event):
        self.text.insert("end", "received entry <FocusOut>\n")
        self.text.see("end")

    def handle_checkbutton(self):
        self.cb.focus_set()
        self.text.insert("end", "received checkbutton command\n")
        self.text.see("end")

e = Example()
tk.mainloop()
```

### Solution 1: call update to force tkinter to process the focus change

In this solution, add a call to `self.root.update()` immediately after changing the focus. This will give tkinter a chance to process the focus change before continuing on with the rest of the code.

```
def handle_checkbutton(self):
    self.cb.focus_set()
    self.root.update()
    self.text.insert("end", "received checkbutton command\n")
    self.text.see("end")
```

### Solution 2: use a ttk checkbutton

Instead of calling `update`, you can use a ttk checkbutton. It has the built-in behavior of setting the focus to the checkbutton when clicked.

First, modify the handler to remove the code that manages the focus:

```
def handle_checkbutton(self):
    self.text.insert("end", "received checkbutton command\n")
    self.text.see("end")
```

Then, use `ttk.Checkbutton` instad of `tk.Checkbutton`:

```
self.cb = ttk.Checkbutton(self.root, command=self.handle_checkbutton, text="Click me")
```

The advantage here is that you don't have to write code to manage the focus.

### Solution 3: add focus handling to the tk Checkbutton class

The third solution is to add a binding to the checkbutton class to mimic the focus stealing behavior of the ttk checkbutton. The advantage here is that you only have to set the binding once and it will apply to every checkbutton in your UI.

First, add the following handler:

```
def set_cb_focus(self, event):
    self.text.insert("end", "setting focus via class binding\n")
    self.text.see("end")
    event.widget.focus_set()
```

Next, add a class binding in the `__init__`. Note that the built-in behavior of the checkbutton is done through class bindings as well. In order to not remove that behavior we need to include `add=True` to the `bind` command, which adds the new behavior rather than replacing the built-in behavior.

```
self.root.bind_class("Checkbutton", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.set_cb_focus)
```

Finally, switch the code back to using a `tk.Checkbutton` rather than `ttk.Checkbutton`:

```
self.cb = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, command=self.handle_checkbutton, text="Click me")
```